# Can I transform AnyPublisher to Published.Publisher?

Tags: combine

So I have a value of type `AnyPublisher<Foo, Error>` and I need to transform it to `Published<Foo>.Publisher` so that I can use it as @Published

so the idea is that I have a MVVM architecture

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
  var body: some View {
    Text(/*Foo has a title, how do I access it? */)
  }
  
}
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
  var cellModels: AnyPublisher<Foo, Error>
  // so the idea is to have and then access it in swiftUI view via viewModel.cellModels2.title
  @Published cellModels2 = convert_somehow_to_publisher(cellModels)
}
```

Apparently I cannot use viewModel.cellModels

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "use it as @Published"? I can't really see a need to every do that, but can you provide an example?

Comment: @NewDev added some details. TL'dr I want to use a value of AnyPublisher in my View. How do I do it?

Comment: You're asking a question about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Looks like what you actually need is to have a `@Published var foo: Foo` property in your view model, and update it from the `cellModels` publisher

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like what you need is to have a `Foo` property on your view model, and update it using the `AnyPublisher<Foo, Error>` publisher that you have.

```swift
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

  var cellModels: AnyPublisher<Foo, Error> = ...
  private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

  @Published var foo: Foo?

  init() {
    cancellable = cellModels.assign(to: \.foo, on: self)
  }
}
```

Then you can access `.foo` in the view normally:

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
  var body: some View {
    Text(viewModel.foo?.title ?? "")
  }
}
```

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but it seems like you are not using @Published actually?